# NotMapped annotation doesn't work with EF6 CodeFirst

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I struggle with my data model. I don't want to store some fields to the DB with EF CodeFirst so I did:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[NotMapped]
public int MyProp{ get; set; }
```

I also set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true but after Update-Database the field appears in the DB.

I use EntityFramework 6.1.3.

So what did I worng? Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: are you sure everything is built correctly and the update was actually executed? What happened in the migration? Does the same error occur using Fluent API .Ignore()?

Comment: Yes the build is ok. I can delete the db tables and add some new members to my model, after `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` every thing is creaded new (and also the `[NotMapped]`fields)...